# What culturing process / experiment needs a "grid" petri dish (one with a vertical division)

Tags: cell-culture

You can buy petri dishes with separations in them like this:

[image: Petri dish with "grid"]

I have studied biology and biochemistry and never come across one of these before.  What cell culturing / experiment would this be used in?

** *Edit:* **

Perhaps it's not cell culturing but instead used for containing different macroscopic organisms like woodlice or something?  But then I'd have thought they'd climb over the divisions.

Comment: I am not sure about 'vertical' division. But in general there is [article](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1365-2672.1967.tb00327.x) describing use of **Divided Petri Dishes**

Comment: We grow plant explants on petri dishes. They grow paifully slowly, so having several on one dish is major space-saver. Howewer, I wouldnt use prefabricated divider. Drawing marker lines on the bottom is usually enough to keep track of what is what.